# How and when would the ":ab" mapping be triggered?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

The `ab` family of command (`iab` and `cab`) could be a huge time saver. However, it is yet unclear when will it be triggered. For example, with the following settings in `_vimrc`:

```
iab sj <c-r>=strftime("20%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")<cr>
cab cab drop C:\users\llinfeng\dropbox
```

For `c` and `i` being "mode-indicator", a complete time-tag will be inserted while in `Insert` mode if one presses `<space>` (or `<ESC>`, `<C-[>`) right after typing `sj`. For the second mapping, the full directory will be inserted in `Command-line` mode if one hits `\` (or `<space>`) right after typing `drop`.

So, it seems that, for `iab`, the following characters will trigger the expansion of an abbreviation defined through `iab`-mapping:

1. `<space>`
2. `<esc>` (or escape in general)
3. Ideally, one may guess the `<tab>` key shall also trigger such expansion. However, for my case (`set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4`, i.e. one "tab" key == 4 spaces"), no expansion would have been triggered.

Then, for `cab`, the following may work to trigger the expansion:

1. `\`
2. `<space>`
3. ??

What is confusing to me is that: what is the thing "laying at the core" that triggers the expansion of an abbreviation defined through `ab`-mapping? And, does there exist a complete list of keys that could trigger such expansion, for both `Insert` mode and `Command-line` mode?

Thank you!

All the best,

-Linfeng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all  exhaustively documented in the vimdocs:

- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#abbreviations

Specifically:

> *An abbreviation is only recognized when you type a non-keyword character.
>   This can also be the `<Esc>` that ends insert mode or the `<CR>` that ends a
>   command.  The non-keyword character which ends the abbreviation is inserted
>   after the expanded abbreviation.  An exception to this is the character `<C-]>`,
>   which is used to expand an abbreviation without inserting any extra
>   characters.*

But it goes on a good few paragraphs detailing precisely what conditions trigger different types of abbreviations. Specifically watch out for the difference between

- full-id (`foo`, `g3`, `-1`)
- end-id (`#i`, `..f`, `$/7`)
- non-id (`def#`, `4/7$`)

abbreviations

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this page. Previously, I was not aware that there is a help file for `abbreviation`. All I knew was about `ab`, for which I found really few explanations in the help file.